# Синхронизация между объектами Workflow

Tags: delphi, классы, связи, workflow, биоинформатика

Создаю универсальный workflow для обработки наших геномных данных. Для этого пишется более или менее стандартный в нашей среде workflow, что-то вроде такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая панель на рисунке - отдельный экземпляр определенного класса (наследника TShape, но не думаю, что это важно) со своими методами, графические и математические проблемы вроде более-менее решены.
У каждого класса есть хотя бы один метод ввода или вывода (бывает, и по нескольку), формат данных на входе и на выходе у разных классов - разные. Одному, условно говоря, нужен массив строк, другому - просто строка, третий выдает самостоятельные массивы строк и массивы целых и  т.п.

Поэтому первый вопрос - как проверять соответствие типов данных? Вот хочу я сделать связь между двумя экземплярами на рисунке, а вдруг нельзя! Либо совсем нельзя, либо нужен еще посредник (конвертор или обработчик). Ничего иного не придумал, кроме как ввести единый энумератор, в котором прописать все возможные варианты типов данных и запрашивать у экземпляров, которые хочу связать, совпадают ли у них типы ввод-вывод по энумератору или нет. Или можно проще придумать способ?

Второй момент. Если использовать TMemoryStream для обмена данными, то как я должен обрабатывать такие ситуации:

- вывод в Stream экземпляром-донором начат. Нужно сообщить экземпляру-акцептору, что можно начинать обрабатывать данные. Как? Создать поток акцептора уснувшим, а затем Resume?
- Экземпляр-акцептор обрабатывает данные быстрее, чем их записывает в Stream экземпляр-донор. Через что разумнее обработать эту ситуацию? Через CriticalSection?

Comment: Ну про связь, первое что приходит в голову: если "каждая панель на рисунке - отдельный экземпляр определенного класса", то для каждой панели реализовать метод, типа `function CanConnect(Obj: TShape): Boolean`, и внутри проверку `Result := Obj.ClassType in [допустимые типы классов для соединения]`. Можно усложнить и вместо `Boolean` использовать свой тип, навроде:  `TCanConnect = (ccNone, ccDirect, ccUseConverter);`

Comment: По поводу второй части: AFAIU вы не сможете из двух потоков исполнения одновременно писать и читать в один `TMemoryStream`, IMHO тут нужен какой-то FIFO буфер, с поддержкой многопоточного доступа. Тогда донор записывает туда данные и сигнализирует акцептору что можно их считать. Пока тот считывает, донор записывает следующий блок [блоки] и так далее.Когда донор не успевает - акцептор просто "спит".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По первому вопросу: нормальное решение.

По второму вопросу: Для синхронизации работы потоков придумано много разных объектов синхронизации, в том числе и события (`TEvent`) и критические секции (`TCriticalSection`). Делать потоку `Resume` - это не по феншую. Чтобы передавать данные через `TMemoryStream` между потоками и одновременно читать и писать, его нужно сделать потокобезопасным (добавить в него критическую секцию). Возможно, для этой задачи лучше подойдет использование каналов (pipe), но мне пока не доводилось с ними работать и я про них мало чего знаю.

Итак, наш наследник от `TMemoryStream`:

```
  TMyCustomMemoryStream = class(TMemoryStream)
  private
    FLock: TCriticalSection;
    FCanReadUpTo: Int64;
    FAllDataWritten: Boolean;
  protected
    function GetSize: Int64; override;
    procedure SetSize(const NewSize: Int64); override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Lock: TCriticalSection read FLock;
    property CanReadUpTo: Int64 read FCanReadUpTo write FCanReadUpTo;
    property AllDataWritten: Boolean read FAllDataWritten write FAllDataWritten;
  end;

{ TMyCustomMemoryStream }

constructor TMyCustomMemoryStream.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;

  FLock := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

destructor TMyCustomMemoryStream.Destroy;
begin
  FLock.Free;

  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TMyCustomMemoryStream.GetSize: Int64;
begin
  FLock.Acquire;
  try
    Result := inherited GetSize;
  finally
    FLock.Release;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyCustomMemoryStream.SetSize(const NewSize: Int64);
begin
  FLock.Acquire;
  try
    inherited SetSize(NewSize);
  finally
    FLock.Release;
  end;
end;
```

`Lock` - критическая секция для доступа к данным. Как-то так:

```
var
DataStream: TMyCustomMemoryStream;

DataStream.Lock.Acquire;
try
  DataStream.Position := 0;
  DataStream.Write(...);
  DataStream.AllDataWritten := True;
finally
  DataStream.Lock.Release;
end;
```

Чтобы другой поток мог читать данные, нужно периодически отпускать критическую секцию, а не писать все за один заход.

Не забываем, что `Position`, после `Lock.Release` может быть совсем не таким, как мы ожидаем, так что его нужно будет запоминать в контексте каждого потока и устанавливать каждый раз в нужное место при записи или чтении.

Теперь поток. который читает данные:

```
  TCustomThread= class(TThread)
  private
    FTerminatedEvent: TEvent;
    FCanReadData: TEvent;
    FData: TMyCustomMemoryStream;
    procedure DoReadData;
    function CheckAndWaitNewData(BytesReaded: Int64): Boolean;
    procedure ClearData;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure ReadData(Data: TMyCustomMemoryStream);
  end;

{ TCustomThread }

constructor TCustomThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);

  FTerminatedEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
  FCanReadData := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
end;

destructor TCustomThread.Destroy;
begin
  Terminate;
  if not Suspended then
    WaitFor;

  ClearData;

  FTerminatedEvent.Free;
  FCanReadData.Free;

  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TCustomThread.ClearData;
begin
  FCanReadData.ResetEvent;
  FreeAndNil(FData);
end;

procedure TCustomThread.DoReadData;
var
  DataPosition: Int64;
  CountToRead: Int64;
begin
  DataPosition := 0;

  while CheckAndWaitNewData(DataPosition) do
  begin
    // read new data
    FData.Lock.Acquire;
    try
      CountToRead := FData.Size - DataPosition;
      FData.Position := DataPosition;
      DataPosition := DataPosition + FData.Read(Buffer, CountToRead);
    finally
      FData.Lock.Release;
    end;

    // process new data
    // ...
  end;

  // all data readed
  ClearData;
end;

function TCustomThread.CheckAndWaitNewData(BytesReaded: Int64): Boolean;
begin
  // returns True on data available or False on AllDataWritten
  Result := FData.Size > BytesReaded;
  while not Result and not FData.AllDataWritten do
  begin
    // wait for 100 ms to check data available again
    if FTerminatedEvent.WaitFor(100) <> wrTimeout then
      Abort;

    Result := FData.Size > BytesReaded;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomThread.Execute;
var
  WOHA: TWOHandleArray;
begin
  WOHA[0] := FCanReadData.Handle;
  WOHA[1] := FTerminatedEvent.Handle;

  try
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      if WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @WOHA, False, INFINITE) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
        DoReadData
      else
        Exit;
    end;
  except
    on EAbort do
      Exit;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomThread.ReadData(Data: TMyCustomMemoryStream);
begin
  if Assigned(FData) then
    raise Exception.Create('Thread is busy!');

  FData := Data;
  FCanReadData.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TCustomThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited TerminatedSet;

  FTerminatedEvent.SetEvent;
end;
```

Предполагается, что поток, читающий данные, ответственен за уничтожение потока данных (возможно не лучшее решение). Поток создается и ожидает события для начала чтения `FCanReadData` или события, сигнализирующего о необходимости завершения работы потока `FTerminatedEvent`. Метод `Execute` можно модифицировать, если нужно делать еще какую-то работу, тогда ожидание должно быть не бесконечным либо вообще нулевым. Чтение данных запускается вызовом метода `ReadData`. Чтение данных продолжается до тех пор, пока не закончатся данные, после чего, если в потоке данных не установлен признак `AllDataWritten` начинается ожидание поступления новых данных с проверкой наличия новых данных каждые 100 мс. Если данные закончились и установлен признак `AllDataWritten`, чтение данных прекращается и поток данных уничтожается.

Answer (score 1):

1. Да, пожалуй. У нас в пакетах, где используются workflow, у всех таких экземпляров есть компонент-хозяин (потомок от TScrollBox с добавленным свойством Canvas), в обязанности которого входят отрисовка всяких стрелочек, создание очереди, автораспределение по поверхности и т.п., и в том числе хранение энумератора с типами данных, а также автосоздание цепочки, если это возможно (Скажем, на входе SAM, а процессу нужны FASTA, тогда пользователю автоматически предлагается создать экземпляр посредника).
2. Мы от потоков отказались, для нас это неудобно, используем собственные классы-контейнеры для массивов. Поскольку не все алгоритмы могут работать с частичными данными, то каждый экземпляр-акцептор имеет свойство в том же энумераторе, нужны ли ему данные полностью или он может брать частично, и если второе - начиная с какого количества уже созданных данных ему можно отсемафорить о начале работы. Поскольку акцепторы никогда не подходят близко к адресам вновь создаваемых данных, критические секции не используются, акцепторы предупреждаются через TEvent.
   Но если нужен именно TMemoryStream, то @kot-da-vinci , на мой взгляд, очень хорошо ответил.

Comment: TScrollBox с поддержкой Canvas? Вы меня заинтриговали. Если задам вопрос, как это сделать, ответите?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Да, пожалуйста, - мне не жалко, всё равно сам собирал и исправлял его по ответам в сети. Задавайте, слежение на [delphi] у меня стоит - увижу, отвечу

Comment: Вот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757456/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-canvas-%D0%BA-tscrollbox