# Добавить Canvas к TScrollBox?

Tags: delphi, canvas, наследование, vcl, компоненты

В качестве контейнера для потомков `TShape` при  [создании Workflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756421/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-workflow) удобно использовать `TScrollBox`. Но у него есть недостаток - отсутствует `Canvas`, что не дает на нем рисовать. Мы обходим эту проблему, размещая TImage на `TScrollBox`, это позволяет рисовать, но добавляет ряд ситуаций, которые приходится обрабатывать.
Я попытался добавить `Canvas` к `TscrollBox`, вот что у меня получилось:

```
 TMyScrollBox = class (TScrollBox)
  private
    FCanvas: TCanvas;
  protected
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
    procedure Paint;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);  override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;


constructor TMyScrollBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FCanvas := TControlCanvas.Create;
  TControlCanvas(FCanvas).Control := Self;
end;


destructor TMyScrollBox.Destroy;
begin
  FCanvas.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyScrollBox.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  FCanvas.Lock;
  try
    FCanvas.Handle := DC;
    try
      TControlCanvas(FCanvas).UpdateTextFlags;
      Paint;
    finally
      FCanvas.Handle := 0;
    end;
  finally
    FCanvas.Unlock;
  end;
end;
```

Вроде все логично. Но не работает. А временами и ошибку выдает. Что здесь не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не хватает обработчика события `WM_PAINT`. Я бы изменил объявление класса так:

```
 TMyScrollBox = class (TScrollBox)
  private
    FCanvas: TCanvas;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT; // добавили обработчик событий
  protected
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
    procedure Paint;
    property Canvas: TCanvas read FCanvas; // добавили свойство в класс, иначе как стандартно обращаться? :)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);  override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

В остальном у вас вроде всё правильно, добавляем обработчик:

```
procedure TMyScrollBox.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  ControlState := ControlState + [csCustomPaint];
  inherited;
  ControlState := ControlState - [csCustomPaint];
end;
```

Дальше можно, конечно, доработать класс в плане устранения мерцания, но это уже для любителей :)

Comment: doublebuffered := True и контрол не будет мерцать. Это свойство заставляет объект отрисоваться в памяти, а потом целой картинкой на экран.

Comment: @AlbertFomin Для наследника TWinControl в общем случае это, конечно, будет работать (не без проблем, правда: как быть с прозрачностью?), но в случае с Canvas - не будет. Чтобы избавиться от мерцания применяют несколько другой подход: https://habrahabr.ru/post/318876/

Comment: интересная статья. пока не надо, но при необходимости, можно идею позаимствовать.